# How to put logo and text side to side

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to put side to side a logo and contact information on HTML header through CSS. Here what I've done so far:

```
<div id="Principal">
    <header>
        <img id="Logo" src="decoupe/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <h2 id="Titre">ENGLISH | OFFRES D'EMPLOIS</h2>
        <div style="display:block;text-align:left"><img align="left" src="decoupe/tel.png" border="0">CONTACTEZ-NOUS<br>
        450.378.0413<br>
        1.800.567.1827</div>
   </header>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#Principal
{
    width:1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px;

}
#Logo
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;

}
#Titre
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;

}
```

What I've done wrong since I want to add background image file with it?

Comment: You should be `float:left` your image. That'll make the h2/div naturally go on the right-hand side of the image.

Comment: I've just done that and no results.

Comment: Your <h2> tag is too wide:

Comment: you might want to close `Principal` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assign some container id to the both content

**HTML**

```
   <header>
    <div id='left-content'>
        <img id="Logo" src="decoupe/logo.png" alt="logo" />
         <h2 id="Titre">ENGLISH | OFFRES D'EMPLOIS</h2>

    </div>
    <div id='right-content'>
        <img src="decoupe/tel.png" border="0"
        />
        <span id='img-content'>CONTACTEZ-NOUS
        <br/>450.378.0413

        <br/>1.800.567.1827
        </span>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

Add width to both the container and make it float:left, use % for making it responsive

```
#Principal {
    width:1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
}
#left-content {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
#right-content {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#right-content img {
 display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
#img-content {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
#Logo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width:15%;
}
#Titre {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ECQr/1/)

Comment: Still the same result.  Nothing change.

Answer (score -1):

Your h2 tag is too wide, try to give some space for the contact information:

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Principal {
    width:1000px;
    border: solid 1px;
}
#Logo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#Titre {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}
#contact {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TRzca/1/)